# Android sharing without having app (e.g., Facebook) installed

Tags: android, sdk, native, sharing

I want to share something via LinkedIn, Facebeook, Twitter, and email apps.  If the user does not have these apps installed, I want to open the sharing service in a browser.  To do this, can I stick to the Android SDK? If so, how would I implement the case in which the user doesn't have the app installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply by using the SDK of the relevant social media system.

In the case of Facebook, you would need to package the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/) into your App and use it directly, as opposed to sending an Intent to the Facebook App.

- [Facebook SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/).
- [Twitter SDK documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries).
- [LinkedIn SDK documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk).